# Angular Directive needs access to variable in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

```
<div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
    <div progressbar="value"></div>
</div>
```

Each campaign has it's own unique property called "percent" that I want the directive to be able to access.

```
myApp.directive('progressbar', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        'progress': '=progressbar'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $element.progressbar({
            value: *** I want this to refer to the correct campaign.percent ***
        })
    }
  }
})
```

I have a feeling I am severely overthinking this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `<div progressbar="campaign.value"></div>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change HTML in order to pass current `campaign` object to directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
    <div progressbar="campaign"></div>
</div>
```

and then in directive you will be able to access campaign object as `$scope.progress`:

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $element.progressbar({
        value: $scope.progress.percent
    });
}
```

Of course you can pass in `percent` value directly as `<div progressbar="campaign.percent"></div>` but I think that it makes sense to provide complete campaign object in case you will need some other properties other then `percent`.